# Why reference projects over packages?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've seen numerous articles and examples about the power of global.json for including references to related projects either directly in the solution, or even in another project/solution elsehwere in the file system, such as explained in this article: https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/the-global-json/

But I really don't see the advantage of doing this over packages. Doing that kind of external referencing (which you could do without global.json before .NET Core, it just wouldn't show in the solution) has what I see as the following problems:

1. It means you must have the same organization of different solutions in the file system, something that can't be enforced, but is now required to work.
2. If you are referencing the source code via filesystem, what happens when you left that project in an uncompilable, incomplete state? If it was a package there would be no impact, since you didn't redeploy your package.

Certainly, if the projects are in the same solution and one depends on another, reference by project away, but if they are not in the same solution, I can't see why you would want to take this approach.

The process of updating a package, as mentioned in the article above, ensures integrity and you don't inadvertently break something which would trickle down to all your other projects using that one was a reference.

The only pro I've seen mentioned is that you always get the latest of that referenced project, while with packages that isn't necessarily true, or depending on your regex reference, you may grab a dev build you didn't want to. But I see that as an advantage, you really DON'T want to automatically be getting the latest, you would only want to when you can 1) Ensure the new version didn't break something and 2) ensure you have a reason to update the newest version.

What's the advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing projects rather than packages just convenience for smaller project it's.

You don't need to build the packages when you do a small change, you don't need a build server and you don't need to update versions of all projects to reference the new assembly.

No reason or point doing that where an assembly is reused across different non-related projects. I've never seen an professional reference that suggest using projects over packages in such scenarios.